# この文で「高い」って何のことでしょうか

Tags: meaning, sentence

あるサイトでこの投稿を見たけれど、意味がよくわかりません。

> 部活の推薦で高校へ行くか、自分の学力で行くか迷っています、、、部活は剣道の推薦で偏差値的には全然普通に受ける高校の方が高いです、、、

これはその投稿のすべての内容ですが、前半は大丈夫ですけど、後半で僕の理解が正しいかどうかはわかりません。二つの選択肢があって、投稿者は推薦のことを考えてるみたいです。後半について僕の理解：

> 部活（の推薦の方）は (in the case of 部活の推薦)、[偏差値的には全然普通に受ける高校の方が高いです]

カッコ内の言葉がよくわからないです。何のことが高いですか？偏差値なのか、部活なのか。部活の推薦があれば、なぜ高い偏差値が必要ですか？普通に受けるって何が普通ですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> カッコ内の言葉がよくわからないです。何のことが高いですか？偏差値なのか、部活なのか。部活の推薦があれば、なぜ高い偏差値が必要ですか？普通に受けるって何が普通ですか？

高いのは、偏差値です。「普通に受ける」は、「一般入試を受ける」ことです。部活の推薦がもらえる高校の偏差値よりも、自分が一般入試を受けるつもりの高校の偏差値のほうが高い、ということです。

原文は少しわかりにくい書き方をしているので、こう言いかえるとわかりやすいかと思います：

> 部活は剣道の推薦です。偏差値的には、推薦をもらえる高校より、全然普通の一般入試で受ける高校の方が高いです。

あるいは、

> 推薦をもらえる部活は、剣道です。推薦をもらえる高校より、一般入試で受ける高校のほうが、偏差値が全然（≂断然）高いです。

部活の推薦（スポーツ推薦）は通常は「専願」で、決まったら別の高校に変更できません。推薦入試は、時期が早いです。１２月ごろに推薦を受けて決まってしまったら、２月ごろにある一般入試は受けません。この人は、推薦を受けて偏差値が低めの高校で妥協すべきか、推薦を受けずに学力でもっと偏差値の高い高校の一般入試にチャレンジすべきか、迷っています。前者だと、偏差値が低めの高校にしか進学できませんが、受験勉強しなくていいし不合格になる可能性もほとんどありません。一方、後者だともっとレベルの高い高校に行けますが、受験勉強しなくてはいけませんし不合格になるリスクもあります。